# Discord.JS Slash Command Invalid Webhook Token after 15 mins

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently made a cooldown discord bot in node.js with Discord.JS library, for it i wanted to use te new Discord.JS v13 to be able to do Slash Commands. In a result my loop is having the error

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Webhook Token
```

I am getting that error with a editReply on the interaction.

Here is the full error

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298
  throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
        ^
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Webhook Token
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
at async InteractionWebhook.editMessage (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:268:15)
at async CommandInteraction.editReply (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:139:21)
at async Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Discord Lab Countdown brokers\commands\command.js:45:21) {
```

The command works fine otherwise but the bot crashes on that after 15 minutes. So i have read that tokens would expire after 15 minutes ?? But i don't know if thats true, and if it is, how to regenerate it while the loop is running ?

Here is the command code :

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    
    // ...
    
    if (interaction.commandName === 'command') {
        // ...
        try {
            // ...
            let time = 60;
            let current = 0;
            
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [myembed]});

            // ...

            let interval = setInterval(async () => {
                current++;
                await interaction.editReply({embeds: [newembed]});
                if(current == time)
                {
                    // ...
                    await interaction.editReply({embeds: [newembed], components: [button_row]});  <--- error points here
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 60000);
        } catch(err) {
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [error]});
        }
                
    }
});
```

I really need help on this because i can't find anything on internet about it,

Thank you very much :D

EDIT : I noticed on the discord.js documentation that slash commands expires after 15 minutes, so i just defered the reply of the command and used normal message instead with `interaction.channel.send()`

Comment: did you manage to solve this problem? I don't want to send a new message with `interaction.channel.send`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the [`MessageComponentInteraction#deferReply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageComponentInteraction?scrollTo=deferReply) method in order to reply to an interaction that waits for a promise to fulfil, this is due to discord invalidating any interaction if there is no action to it within `3000` miliseconds which is 3 seconds, if you followed upto the answer your code would look something around the following:

```js
 try {
            // ...
            let time = 60;
            let current = 0;
            await interaction.deferReply()
            await interaction.editReply({embeds: [myembed]});

            // ...
            let interval = setInterval(async () => {
                current++;
                await interaction.editReply({embeds: [newembed]});
                if(current == time)
                {
                    // ...
                    await interaction.editReply({embeds: [newembed], components: [button_row]});  <--- error points here
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 60000);
        } catch(err) {
            await interaction.reply({embeds: [error]});
        }
                
    }
```

Comment: You can't deferReply after a reply, I noticed later on that slash commands has a validity of 15 minutes so i just defered the reply of the interaction and used normal message for my loop and it works.

Comment: You can defer the reply before replying to the interaction, made suitable changes to my answer following the same.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that an interaction token is valid 15mins so i noticed that you can do follow ups to change token but that also sends a new reply so new message which isnt what i wanted, so i just used normal message with interaction.channel.send instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for Discord.JS v13 since that's no longer the currently supported version, but on Discord.JS v14 (which I assume people getting this error in 2023 will be using) you can store the message on a constant and then edit it later like a normal message.

```
// You need to send "fetchReply: true" to have the promise resolve to a Message object
const messageFromInteractionReply = await interaction.deferReply({ fetchReply: true });
// You can also just use a normal reply here and send your message content

// run all the code you need for more than 15 minutes

messageFromInteractionReply.edit({content: "Hello after 15 minutes!"})
```

Reference in the Discord.JS docs:

[InteractionReplyOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/InteractionReplyOptions)

[Message.edit](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=edit)